# Flask sqlalchemy: error when query using sqlachemy core

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

Due to I have create many APIs in MySQLdb module, and now I need to shift to sqlalchemy, I wish to use the sqlalchemy core so that not many changes needed. I am using MySQL now.

When I change to `db.session.execute` that previously work for Mysqldb using `cur.execute(`), error occurred.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Stock' is not defined
```

Below is the code with sqlalchemy

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/KJ/<Stock>', methods=['GET'])
def KJstock(Stock):
     try:
        call = db.session.execute("SELECT * FROM KJ WHERE Stock LIKE %s",(Stock,))
        col = ['index','Stock','Name','MACD','STOCH','RSI','ATR','Bollinger','SMA','SMAcross',]

        c = call.fetchall()
        d = [OrderedDict(zip(col,t)) for t in c]
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    return jsonify({'Stock': d})
```